# ASCII change Cr and Lf to the characters "¬", and "¶"

Tags: c#, .net, string

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    const char ASC_Cr = (char)13;  //Cr
    const char ASC_Lf = (char)10;  //Lf
```

...etc etc... more code here

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
        string ReadString;
        ReadString = serialPort1.ReadLine();

        ReadString = ReadString.Replace(ASC_Cr, ("¬"));
        ReadString = ReadString.Replace(ASC_Lf, "¶");
        Console.WriteLine("Read:" + ReadString);
        }
```

I am trying to read the serial port and ASCII change cr and lf to the characters "¬", and "¶" so that the debug shows exactly what I receive.

However I get the following error.

"The best overloaded method match for 'string.Replace(char, char)' has some invalid argument"
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single-quotes, not double:

```
ReadString.Replace(ASC_Cr, ('¬'));
```

C# uses single-quotes to denote a char, and double-quotes to denote a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use single-quotes, not double quotes to represent character in c#:

ReadString.Replace(ASC_Cr, ('¬'));